# agm/core polyline from firebase

Tags: android, angular, firebase-realtime-database, angular-google-maps

How to store values in firebase from android like this:

```
polyline : [
        {
            latitude:  39.8282,
            longitude: -98.5795
        },
        {
            latitude: 37.772,
            longitude: -122.214
        },
        {
            latitude: 21.291,
            longitude: -157.821
        }}
```

so it can be used by agm/core's polyline. Firebase doesn't accept arrays and it seems like the only way to pass the polyline directive a set of coordinates and then iterate through it to draw out the polyline path would be as an array. Otherwise, I guess, I would have to pass individual latlong points to angular and create an array this way but I would prefer not doing it this way.

Comment: But [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) accept arrays. You should give it a try.

Comment: I just want to make a note here, in case somebody else has the same issue, that @AlexMamo's suggestion worked. Tested it using Firestore using the format